# Can't boot Linux from an external USB SSD drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, ssd, live-cd

Windows 7 OS. Is there any difference between `Linux Live CD` and Linux installation on an external `USB SSD drive` in point of view of boot? I can boot **Linux LiveCD** without a problem when set boot order to "CD/DVD" in boot menu setup, but can't boot Linux from SSD drive when set boot order to "USB storage" in boot menu. When I try to boot Linux from SSD drive, it just hungs on black screen with message and a blinking cursor:

```
GRUB loading.
Welcome to GRUB!
_
```

At the end of Linux installation, GRUB was installed on "/dev/sdb" (SSD drive).

Boot Info Script [results](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=mBjrtR6P).

Comment: On my system no USB boot entry works, but external device is seen as a hard drive boot choice. Why PAE 32 bit version? If system can run Windows 7, it should run newer versions. And any really old hardware that may need PAE would probably not work with a SSD which needs AHCI. Not sure if AHCI even works thru USB though.

Comment: When I installed Debian, installer prompted to select the Linux kernel to install, from a 4 versions: `linux-image-3.2.0.-4-486, linux-image-3.2.0.-686-pae, linux-image-486, linux-image-686-pae.` Since I wasn't sure what is difference and which one will suit better, I just chosen the version that was highlighted, linux-image-3.2.0-4-686-pae. Which kernel vers. will suit better? The laptop isn't too old, 2009.

Comment: Did you download the 32bit version? Most Windows 7 systems would work with 64 bit version better. Only if you have less than about 2.5GB of RAM should you use 32 bit version. I actually run 64 bit on system with only 1.5GB but with more than one large app it starts using swap. And what video? If decent video card chip Unity should work, but I prefer fallback with it old fashioned menus.

Comment: I installed from "debian-7.6.0-i386-netinst" .iso. RAM is 4Gb. Dedicated video card 256Mb NVIDIA GeForce 9300M GS. Does it make sence to reinstall bootloader?

Comment: I know nothing about Debian, and I think admins will close thread as this is an Ubuntu forum. But you should really be using a 64 bit distribution.